# Ravendb select - update multiple row

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to select and update multiple row from ravendb, but it recursively update same rows. Namely first 100 rows. There is no changes.

Here is my code. How can I select some rows, Update some fields of each rows and do it again and again until my job finished.

```
var currentEmailId = 100;
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
     var goon = true;
     while(goon){
          var contacts = session.Query<Contacts>().Where(f => f.LastEmailId < currentEmailId).Take(100);
          if(contacts.Any()){
                foreach(var contact in contacts){
                    EmailOperation.Send(contact, currentEmailId);
                    contact.LastEmailId = currentEmailId;
                 }
             session.SaveChanges();
           }
           else{
             goon = false
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're doing a query immediately after saving changes, without letting the indexes update after save changes. Thus, you're getting back the same items. To fix that, you can tell SaveChanges to wait until indexes are updated. Your code would look something like this:

Try this:

```
var goon = true;
var currentEmailId = 100;
while (goon)
{
    using (var session = store.OpenSession())
    {
        var contacts = session.Query<Contacts>()
            .Where(f => f.LastEmailId < currentEmailId)
            .Take(100);

        if(contacts.Any())
        {
            foreach(var contact in contacts)
            {
                EmailOperation.Send(contact, currentEmailId);
                contact.LastEmailId = currentEmailId;
            }

            // Wait for the indexes to update when calling SaveChanges.
            DbSession.Advanced.WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), false);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            goon = false
        }
     }
}
```

If you're updating many contacts at once, you may wish to consider using using [Streaming query results](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/commands/querying/how-to-stream-query-results) combined with [BulkInsert](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/bulk-insert/how-to-work-with-bulk-insert-operation) to update many Contacts en mass.

Comment: does WaitForIndexesAfterSaveChanges is safe? For example for only one second.

Comment: Yeah, it's safe. It will block until the appropriate indexes are updated, so that you won't query stale data. (I'm now in the habit of calling that quite regularly in my production apps.)

Comment: How many contacts will typically be updated? Tens? Hundreds? Thousands? As I mentioned at the end of the post, if you're updating many Contacts whenever this function is called, you might want to consider Streaming+BulkInsert. It'll be faster and you won't have to deal with stale indexes.

Comment: Streaming is a good alternative, but how can I retry on any broken? I must know which contacts got the email before the broken. I have 200 thousands contact for daily newsletter. Sometimes I have 2 newsletter one day.

Comment: Retry what? Retry the email? I'm not sure what you mean "retry on any broken."

Comment: I mean, If operation stop on somewhere of the list due to any reason, maybe a bug or a connection problem, how can I know what is latest contact I sent the mail. Maybe I can cache Latest contact_id but I ask that is there any option setting a value when straming?